# Can I get a 100% dedicated CPU to my critical process?

Tags: performance, cpu

I am looking for a way to get a consistent time measurement (<1% difference between the different runs) for my program under Ubuntu 14.04. `perf stat` shows that I still get quite a few context switches although my program never gives control to OS (no I/O, no memory allocation etc.). I do run the program using `sudo nice -n -20` on a shielded CPU (my `Intel i7 CPU` has four physical cores, hyper-threading is disabled in BIOS) with `-k on` switch to `cset shield`.

I understand that the unmovable kernel processes are the source of context switches. So, my questions is: is there a way to set up shielding at boot, so that those unmovable processes run on the non-shielded CPUs to start with? In the case that the answer is "no", is there another way I can obtain a pure environment for my critical process under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Im going to stick my neck out here and say that this isnt possible on Linux in general.

In SMP systems there is a scheduler running on each core, which is why you are still getting context switches. If your application is really that critical, perhaps you should be using some kind of RTOS, rather than linux.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the schedtool package.  It offers CPU locking facilities, and a choice of CPU schedulers to the user.

---

Worried about the GUI affecting things?  From a virtual terminal, kill X and see.  Probably with an i7 CPU, there are enough cores to make that irrelevant.  It's all a matter of controlling shared resources, with the CPU being only one such resource.  Some resources are so plentiful, it's hard to remember they're shared, like memory. The more you ensure your "critical process" is not delayed by anything else, the worse your general purpose Linux OS will behave from a user interaction viewpoint.

Comment: Would this substitute the need to use the Server edition (as per the next reply)?

Comment: With the -R policy, I went down from 32 context switches to only 4. Nice! May be the -B policy would be a better one (especially since much of the variance I get now seems to be due to the difference in the number of cache misses), but unfortunately this policy does not seem to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When I want run to run comparable experiments I: Lock the CPU clock frequencies or governor, so as to avoid possible response differences; Force the task to run on a specific CPU (if not multi-threaded); If there is any disk I/O involved, or any other source of caching, flush the memory cache between runs for a fair comparison.

For my experiments that has always been good enough, but perhaps not for yours.
I'll edit this with more details if desired.

Edit: I forgot to mention, and very important. I only use Ubuntu server edition for this type of work. Desktops have way to much other stuff always running. and so an otherwise "idle" computer really is no where near idle. On an idle server, there is only the occasional cron job, which can and does mess up that run of the experiment.

For example I did 262 runs of a program that takes on average 5.6217 seconds to execute. The run time standard deviation was 0.0119 seconds and very worst cases overall were +0.68% and -0.56%. I forced CPU 7 and forced performance mode (but note that even in performance mode intel i7 processors can back off the clock frequency by themselves.)

Furthermore, if I disable the intel_pstate frequency governor and use the acpi_cpufreq one in "powersave" mode, basically locking the CPUs at the minimum pstate (lowest frequency), then I get about +/- 0.01% run time variations on an average run time of 13.22 seconds.

Comment: The results that you quote are very impressive. However, I am afraid that running a server would require expertise in system administration that I do not possess. Could you please describe your system's setup in more detail: Do you have a GUI? Which of the Desktop edition's conveniences do you sacrifice to run the Server edition? (I mean, there must be a reason why Desktop edition exists...)

Comment: I do not have a GUI, I use pure Ubuntu servers. And yes, one gives up all Desktop edition conveniences to run servers. For the type of work you described, and in my experience, there is simply too much background activity going on in Desktops to get reasonable run to run comparisons. However, I am not familiar with some of the other tools mentioned in the other replies.

Comment: As for "taskset" mentioned below, that is what I use. I think you will find that the scheduler will stay away from the heavily loaded CPU by itself, without any extra directives. However note that there are some things that simply must run on that CPU

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by non-shielded processors but they way to assign any process to a cpu is to use **taskset**. You can even use it on kernel modules to force crude NUMA policy.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Say I want to run my critical process on CPU number 3. How do I force all kernel processes to stay away from that CPU? Also, is this a safe thing to do? (i.e. there is probably a reason why `cset shield` does not move those kernel processes...)

Comment: You could  do it all with taskset honestly and a bit of scripting but the "right way" to do it these days is with cgroups. You'll want to assess all the processes in your system and start manipulating where they start at the init script level. The worse thing you can do is hurt your performance. htop and perf top are your friends. Giving a single process exclusive access is a bit of a waste because it'll have to sleep for IO sometime and not letting another processes schedule during that window just hurts the overall perf. Be pragmatic about it and pay close attention to htop.